# Why doesn't add method accept my inputs?

Tags: java, arraylist, append

So far this is my problematic code, assume everything else is made and done:

```
public GameRecord[] updateHighScoreRecords(GameRecord[] highScoreRecords, String name, int level, int score) {
    // write your code after this line

    int i = 0;
    for (GameRecord gr : highScoreRecords){
        if (gr.getScore() >= gr.getScore()){
            highScoreRecords.add(i+(gr.getLevel()-level),(Object) new GameRecord(name, level, score)); /*
            *adds the new GameRecord in at the (i+gr's level - level)th iteration.
            *note it does this because of the assumtion that highScoreRecords is ordered becuase of only using this function
            */
           break; //no more need to continue the loop
        }


        i += 1;
    }
    return highScoreRecords;
}
```

as you may have noticed, my code is part of a course, so that is why I'm assuming all other implementations are perfect.

Comment: Arrays don't have methods.

Comment: `highScoreRecords` is an array of `GameRecord` objects....it does not have an `add` method...

Comment: @immibis In the context of this question, you can say you're right - but: every array is also an instance of `java.lang.Object` so it has all methods that are defined on `Object` (like `hashCode` and `equals`)

Comment: @immibis They do, but they're all static methods.

Comment: @x-x Are `equals` and `hashCode` (thanks to Erwin Bolwidt for pointing that out) static? I think not.

Comment: @immibis yes, I meant its own, non-inherited methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in a `GameRecord[] highScoreRecords` array,

but calling a List method `add` - this does not exist on an `Array`.  You should be getting a compile error.

If you are sure that the array has capacity for insertion then you could do

```
highScoreRecords[i+(gr.getLevel()-level)] = new GameRecord(name, level, score);
```

but I guess you would be better off using a `List` like `ArrayList`, and keeping your existing code.  For this you will to pass a List to the method not an Array.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that there were different `List`/`Array` structures, I thought that they were all just `ArrayList` which is what my course made it seem.

Comment: No Arrays and Lists are very very different.

Answer (score 1):

Java arrays are not dynamic data structures,

```
highScoreRecords.add(i+(gr.getLevel()-level),
    (Object) new GameRecord(name, level, score));
```

I think you wanted

```
// Using a List.
GameRecord[] updateHighScoreRecords(List<GameRecord> highScoreRecords, 
    String name, int level, int score) {
```

Also, don't cast to `Object`. That's [raw-type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)ing.